# Multiple input type="file" validation

Tags: html

I've created a functionality for user(s) to be able to upload multiple images to a website with different `html` input tags like so:

```
<input type="file" name="photos[]" required>
<input type="file" name="photos[]">
<input type="file" name="photos[]">
<input type="file" name="photos[]">
<input type="file" name="photos[]">
```

The idea is to allow only a maximum of 5 images to be uploaded. I know I can just do `<input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>` but this doesn't allow them to choose files from different folders from their device, hence the reason why I have multiple `<input type="file">`.

I know this pattern works well with radios and checkboxes, but the issue I'm having now is to validate the field as **one** and not multiple inputs.

I know there are javascript/jquery libraries I can use to achieve this, but I really do not want to use any.

Is there a workaround towards achieving this?

Comment: The post request for this `form` should send a single array `$_POST['photos']`, with your pictures inside. Then you can check if the number of images is at most 5 with `count($_POST['photos'])`.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, what if I want to validate before the form is submitted? I've tried it, but it is validating for each `<input>`.

Comment: If you do a custom submission using `event.preventDefault()` on the submit button click listener and artificial `form.submit()` at the end, them you can do a preliminary JS check and you can define your own check rules for each form element (like caring about a single input instead of all 5). The downside for this is that you will have to add your check rules for each element in the form manually.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I don't want to manually check for each element. I just wish there was a way I could check for all elements, just like radios and checkboxes.

Comment: Then, how about disabling the click listener on the submit button and do a count check for the `$("input[name=photos]")` with each input event? If the count is higher than 1 but lower than 5, then you can re-enable the click listener. Like this, you won't have to touch the validation rules when the submit is actually clicked.

Comment: I'll give it a try.